# 配列リテラルで配列を結合したい

Tags: javascript

下記のような結合を行いたいのですが方法がわからなく教えていただきたいです。

```
let objA = {name:"A",age:"10"};
let objB = {name:"B",age:"20"};
```

objAとobjBを結合しobjCへ格納
    `objC → {name:"A",age:"10"},{name:"B",age:"20"};`

-- 追記---
最終的に上で作ったocjCを別のオブジェクトに結合したいです。

```
let objD = [
             {name:"D",age:"30"}
             ,objC    //{name:"A",age:"10"},{name:"B",age:"20"}
           ];
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `let objC = [objA, objB];` ということですか？

Comment: BLUEPIXY さん objDを配列にしそこにobjCの内容を配列として結合することで実現できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: `objC`を埋め込むより、`push`した方がよくないですか？(あるいは`push.apply`)

Comment: たしかに配列の結合なら pushのがいいですね、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

配列にしたいということでしょうか？
であれば、 `let objC = [objA, objB]` で実現できます。

そうでない場合、結合されたobjCについて、具体的な説明があればお求めの回答も付きやすいかと思います。

Comment: KONDO Daisuke さんご回答ありがとうございます。質問に追記いたしました。

Comment: objDを配列にしそこにobjCの内容を配列として結合することで実現できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 求めている答が得られた場合、承認済みにしてください。
既存の回答に付けることもできますし、ご自身で実現した内容を回答として書き、承認済みにすることもできます。

Comment: すみません、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

ES6(ES2015)以降には、[スプレッド演算子](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)(`...`)があります。

```
let objA = {name:"A",age:"10"};
let objB = {name:"B",age:"20"};
let objC = [objA, objB];
```

という状態だとすると、
このように配列リテラルに配列を埋め込めます。

```
let objD = [ {name:"D",age:"30"}, ...objC ];

/* let objD = [ {name:"D",age:"30"}, objC[0], objC[1] ] と同じ
[ { name: 'D', age: '30' },
  { name: 'A', age: '10' },
  { name: 'B', age: '20' } ]
*/
```

あるいは、このように関数の引数部分にも使えます。

```
let objD = [ {name:"D",age:"30"} ];
objD.push(...objC);

// objD.push(objC[0], objC[1]) と同じ
```

ES5 などを使っていて、スプレッド演算子が使えない場合は、[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)、[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)、[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) などのメソッドで操作するしかありません。